# How do you use date-format variables in a npm package.json scripts?

Tags: node.js, npm, date-format, package.json, cucumberjs

I've created a CucumberJs solution and I'm trying to set a script in my npm package.json that kicks off the testing and also creates a output file.   The trouble I'm having is setting a date into the file.
I know the following works:

```
{
  "name": "UI-test-automation",
  "version": "1.1.0",
  "description": "Integration Regression UI Test Automation",
  "main": "autoTest.js",
  "scripts": {
      "start": "node ./node_modules/.bin/cucumber-js --tags @RegressionTestSuite --format json:./results/log.json",
```

This will create a log.json result file in the /results directory.  I want to add a date time to the log file.   I tried using:

```
{
  "name": "UI-test-automation",
  "version": "1.1.0",
  "description": "Integration Regression UI Test Automation",
  "main": "autoTest.js",
  "scripts": {
      "start": "node ./node_modules/.bin/cucumber-js --tags @RegressionTestSuite --format json:./results/log_`date +\\%Y\\\\%m\\\\%d_%H%M\\`.json",
```

but this isn't working.  Anyone know now I can add a date into the file name so that the log file will have the current date time?

---

Solution

---

I couldn't get the dang slashes to work, so my cop-out was to use dashes:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./node_modules/.bin/cucumber-js --tags @New2 --format json:./results/log__`date +%Y-%m-%m__%H-%M`.json",
```

Comment: Is it working from the command line? When you run the npm run script does the executed command look the same as when you run directly from the command line? My guess is that when the npm script is being transformed to run something is not being correctly transformed.

Comment: I guess my real question is how can is us the CucumberJS --format option in a way to include a time stamp.

Comment: I'll just use dashes.